Getting error in db.create() while connecting from python flask to postgres db
I was trying to create a web app with flask and postgres DB by refering the youtube vedio but getting error while creating the tables and columns using db.create_all().
Below is the code and error. Could you please help?
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from send_mail import send_mail

app = Flask(__name__)

ENV = 'dev'

if ENV == 'dev':
    app.debug = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:Password-1@localhost/lexus'
else:
    app.debug = False
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = ''

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Feedback(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'feedback'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True)
    dealer = db.Column(db.String(200))
    rating = db.Column(db.Integer)
    comments = db.Column(db.Text())

    def __init__(self, customer, dealer, rating, comments):
        self.customer = customer
        self.dealer = dealer
        self.rating = rating
        self.comments = comments


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer = request.form['customer']
        dealer = request.form['dealer']
        rating = request.form['rating']
        comments = request.form['comments']
        # print(customer, dealer, rating, comments)
        if customer == '' or dealer == '':
            return render_template('index.html', message='Please enter required fields')
        if db.session.query(Feedback).filter(Feedback.customer == customer).count() == 0:
            data = Feedback(customer, dealer, rating, comments)
            db.session.add(data)
            db.session.commit()
            #send_mail(customer, dealer, rating, comments)
            return render_template('success.html')
        return render_template('index.html', message='You have already submitted feedback')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

getting below error:
>>> db.create_all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Haswath G N\.virtualenvs\FEEDBACK-APP-trygjtNU\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 900, in create_all
    self._call_for_binds(bind_key, "create_all")
  File "C:\Users\Haswath G N\.virtualenvs\FEEDBACK-APP-trygjtNU\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 871, in _call_for_binds
    engine = self.engines[key]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Haswath G N\.virtualenvs\FEEDBACK-APP-trygjtNU\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 687, in engines
    app = current_app._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Haswath G N\.virtualenvs\FEEDBACK-APP-trygjtNU\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 508, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.
>>>

I am new this web development, please help.

There is no call to db.create_all() in this code.  However the suggested duplicate explains the cause of the issue and how to fix it
